# When to calculate the bias corrected geometric mean

Tags: unbiased-estimator, lognormal-distribution, geometric-mean

Most sources give a simple equation to compute the geometric mean (GeoMean) of data samples from a lognormal distribution.

```
GeoMean = exp(m)
```

where *m* is the mean of the natural (base e) logarithms of the values

A bias-corrected equation is given in: Parkin, T. B. & Robinson, J. A. Statistical Evaluation of Median Estimators for Lognormally Distributed Variables. Soil Sci. Soc. Am. J. 57, 317–323 (1993).

```
GeoMean = exp(m - s^2/2n)
```

Here, *m* and *s* are the mean and standard deviation of the natural logarithms of the values, and *n* is the number of values in the sample. With large *n* (and/or small *s*), this equation approaches the simpler, more commonly used, equation. But with small n and/or large s, the results can differ enough to matter.

Here is a heat map to get a sense of how large the correction is. Each value is the correction factor to multiply the simple (traditional) GeoMean by to obtain the bias-corrected GeoMean. As expected, the correction only matters with large GeoSD and small sample size.
[image]

My questions:

- Is this bias-corrected equation correct? I have not seen it elsewhere, and can't find any mentions searching Google or Wikipedia. Should it always be used?
- If it is correct and recommended, why? Where does the bias come from?

Answer (score 5):

The title of the paper says "lognormally distributed variables". Under the assumption that the variables are distributed $LN(\mu,\sigma)$, the logs are normally distributed $N(\mu,\sigma)$ and:
\begin{align}
m &\sim N\left(\mu,\frac\sigma{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
s^2 &\sim \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\chi^2(n-1)
\end{align}
Using those in Mathematica I get:
\begin{align}
E\left[\exp\left(\ \ \ \ \ m \phantom{\frac{1}{m}\ }\right)\right] &=\exp\left(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2n}\right)\\
E\left[\exp\left(m-\frac{s^2}{2n}\right)\right] &=\exp\left(\mu+\frac{\sigma^4}{4n^3}+O(n^{-4})\right)\end{align}
where the actual geometric mean is just $\exp(\mu)$.

So the correction term indeed reduces the bias substantially.

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky, what sort of details would you like to see for the bounty?

Comment: My questions: Why is the usual equation biased? Citations for it. Why isn't it used routinely (is there any disagreement)?  How does it affect computations for a t-test (or ANOVA) to compare GeoMeans? How does it affect calculating the ratio of two GeoMeans?

Comment: The usual equation is biased because $m$ is an unbiased estimator of the mean of the log of the data, $exp$ is a convex function, and Jensen's inequality tells us so.  Note that bias correction methods don't necessarily remove all the bias, they just tend to remove the most important terms (in $O(n^{-\dots})$ expansions), leaving some, presumably much smaller, bias behind.

Comment: On the comments, here are some quick answers using $GM[X]=\exp(E[\ln X])$ for geometric mean.
1) The formulas here probably aren't routine because there aren't that many situations requiring $GM[X]$ rather than $E[X]$ or $E[\ln X]$.
2) Instead of testing for significant difference between $GM[X]$ and $GM[Y]$, it seems simpler to use an ordinary t-test for significant difference between $E[\ln X]$ and $E[\ln Y]$.
3) If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $GM[X/Y]=GM[X]/GM[Y]$.

Comment: @MattF. I find your comment a bit hard to follow, partly because you seem to use (GM[X] in two ways, to refer to the usual GeoMean and to the small n corrected GeoMean.  Also it is "simpler" to do t-test on logs... but is the answer right? accuracy is more important than simplicity.

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky, I agree that there are two different questions: “do the geometric means differ significantly between X and Y?, vs “do the means differ significantly between log X and log Y?” They might have different answers. I’m saying that the second question is simpler to answer, and in most situations it’s an equally appropriate or helpful question.